# Converting JSON to table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a Web project where the client application communicates with the DB via JSONs.

The initial implementation took place with SQL Server 2012 (NO JSON support and hence we implemented a Stored Function that handled the parsing) and now we are moving to 2016 (YES JSON support).

So far, we are reducing processing time by a significant factor (in some cases, over 200 times faster!).

There are some interactions that contain arrays that need to be converted into tables. To achieve that, the `OPENJSON` function does **ALMOST** what we need.

In some of these (array-based) cases, records within the arrays have one or more fields that are also OBJECTS (in this particular case, also arrays), for instance:

```
    [{
        "Formal_Round_Method": "Floor",
        "Public_Round_Method": "Closest",
        "Formal_Precision": "3",
        "Public_Precision": "3",
        "Formal_Significant_Digits": "3",
        "Public_Significant_Digits": "3",
        "General_Comment": [{
            "Timestamp": "2018-07-16 09:19",
            "From": "1",
            "Type": "Routine_Report",
            "Body": "[To + Media + What]: Comment 1",
            "$$hashKey": "object:1848"
        }, {
            "Timestamp": "2018-07-16 09:19",
            "From": "1",
            "Type": "User_Comment",
            "Body": "[]: Comment 2",
            "$$hashKey": "object:1857"
        }, {
            "Timestamp": "2018-07-16 09:19",
            "From": "1",
            "Type": "Routine_Report",
            "Body": "[To + Media + What]: Comment 3",
            "$$hashKey": "object:1862"
        }]
    }, {
        "Formal_Round_Method": "Floor",
        "Public_Round_Method": "Closest",
        "Formal_Precision": "3",
        "Public_Precision": "3",
        "Formal_Significant_Digits": "3",
        "Public_Significant_Digits": "3",
        "General_Comment": []

    }]
```

Here, `General_Comment` is also an array.

When running the command:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@_l_Table_Data)
  WITH (    Formal_Round_Method                 NVARCHAR(16)    '$.Formal_Round_Method'               ,
            Public_Round_Method                 NVARCHAR(16)    '$.Public_Round_Method'               ,
            Formal_Precision                    INT             '$.Formal_Precision'                  ,
            Public_Precision                    INT             '$.Public_Precision'                  ,
            Formal_Significant_Digits           INT             '$.Formal_Significant_Digits'         ,
            Public_Significant_Digits           INT             '$.Public_Significant_Digits'         ,
            General_Comment                     NVARCHAR(4000)  '$.General_Comment'                   
        ) ;
```

[`@_l_Table_Data` is a variable holding the JSON string]

we are getting the column `General_Comment = NULL` even though the is data in there (at least in the first element of the array).

I guess that I should be using a different syntax for those columns that may contain **OBJECTS** and not **SIMPLE VALUES**, but I have no idea what that syntax should be.

Comment: you should think about your DB design. it seems like you should have 2 tables. one for comments and one for whatever the parent entity is.

Comment: Thank you @PhilippSander, but that direction would require the creation of several tens of new tables (I provided just one example) as well as many `JOIN`s to be added (performance). In the meantime, I found a very simple solution (lost the link to MS's page so I'm adding it as the answer to my original post). Cheers!!!!

Comment: those don't sound like valid arguments to me, but it's your choice.
you can handle the performance by using other tools that your DB provides

Comment: @PhilippSander, it is a very long time I realized that people have different strategies, approaches and priorities when designing systems. One of mine is to keep the result as simple as possible without damaging flexibility and maintainability of the result. In this context, keeping the total number of tables as small as possible is one of my preferred techniques. Still, this is very much a matter of taste and hence, what is suitable (and valid) for me does not necessarily have to be suitable (or valid) for others.

Comment: that's fair. As I said it's your choice. I just wanted to point it out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a Microsoft page that actually solves the problem.

Here is how the query should look like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@_l_Table_Data)
  WITH (    Formal_Round_Method        NVARCHAR(16)    '$.Formal_Round_Method'               ,
            Public_Round_Method        NVARCHAR(16)    '$.Public_Round_Method'               ,
            Formal_Precision           INT             '$.Formal_Precision'                  ,
            Public_Precision           INT             '$.Public_Precision'                  ,
            Formal_Significant_Digits  INT             '$.Formal_Significant_Digits'         ,
            Public_Significant_Digits  INT             '$.Public_Significant_Digits'         ,
            General_Comment            NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.General_Comment'   AS JSON                
    ) ;
```

So, you need to add `AS JSON` at the end of the column definition and (God knows why) the type **MUST** be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Very simple indeed!!!